# Change Toolbar Icon Settings in GNOME on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-10.04, icons, toolbar, label

I have installed the new Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and do not see where I can change the toolbar icon settings (for all Gnome/GTK apps) such that I only display icons, not text labels beside the icons. Does anyone know how to fix this?

In Ubuntu 8.04 LTS, there was a setting for this, but Ubuntu 10.04 LTS doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do it,as follow,

lgx@Flying-Pig:~$ gconf-editor
 lgx@Flying-Pig:~$

/desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_style

```
change value to "icons"
```